# Rounding in IEEE double precision computer arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, machine-precision

Wanted to check whether I executed this arithmetic expression correctly:

$$(1 + (2^{-51} + 2^{-52} + 2^{-53})) − 1$$

My process follows:
$1.[00...00]\cdot 2^{0}+0.[0...010]\cdot 2^{0}+0.[0...001]\cdot 2^{0}+0.[00...00]1\cdot 2^{0}-1.[00...00]\cdot 2^{0} \rightarrow$
$0.[000...011]1\cdot 2^{0}= 0.[000...100]\cdot 2^{0}=2^{-50}=4\epsilon_{mach}$

Much help in verifying my process

Comment: The numerical experiment confirms this conclusion. The rounding rule is "rounding to even"?

Comment: thank you, I wanted to make sure the rounding on $0.[000...100]⋅2^{0}$ was right

Comment: If you write this down, you need to care about the order of operations, that is, you should first explicitly compute the rounding effect on $fl(1+7⋅2^{-53})=fl(1+3.5⋅2^{-52})=1+4⋅2^{-52}=1+2^{-50}$ and then subtract one.